# Question about vector in parametric form in relation to perpendicular plane

Tags: calculus

I am quite new to calculus, and I have been staring at the following question for an hour now, without any results:

A plane is placed perpendicular to the curve $\mathbf r(t)=0.5t^2\mathbf i+t\mathbf j+2t\mathbf k$ at point (2,2,4). What is the distance between point (3,4,3) and the perpendicular plane?

I understand that the derivate of $\mathbf r$ would give me the tangent, which would deliver the a,b, and c necessary to establish the Cartesian formula for the plane… Then calculating the distance would be easy.

I am stuck at the first bit, because the derivative comes out (t,1,2) and this is not usable as it stands.

Could anybody help out?

Thank you

Comment: The value of t at the point (2, 2, 4) is 2

Comment: @vladz Thanks! So I should that information in order to rewrite the derivative as (2,1,2) and then use that to determine the cartesian formula of the plane?

Comment: @vladz and even if I try that, the plane comes out as 2x+y+2z+d=0; after entering (2,2,4), d comes out as -14. However the distance between 2x+y+2x-14=0 and (3,4,3) then comes out as 2/3, while the options given are 1,2,3 and 4. I am lost...